# Angular Material 2 md-input is not focusing when i setValue to the formGroup

Tags: angular, focus, material-design, angular-reactive-forms

Something weird is happening with md-input focus:

This is one of the element i have

```
<md-input-container dividerColor="warn">
        <input md-input placeholder="Code..." formControlName="code">
 </md-input-container>
```

This is the method i subscribe and set the value to the formGroup:

```
getOneItem() {
this._objectsService.getOneItem(this.id).subscribe(
  resObjectsData => {
    delete resObjectsData._id;
    this.form.setValue(resObjectsData); // Here i am setting the value
  }, error => this.errorMsg = error
);
```

The object on the view is loading as excepted but the md-input text field is not focusing. The other types like date,time,select,number are focusing just fine. Here is an screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<md-input formControlName="code" placeholder="Code..."></md-input>` without md-input-container

Answer (score 0):

I also wasn´t able to set the input focused, so I just get rid of the placeholder and set a fixed label, just a workaround.

```
<md-input-container floatingPlaceholder="false">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" md-input formControlName="fieldName">
</md-input-container>
```